# How to build spring boot application which should import spring context file from dependent jars?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to create new application as Spring boot application. But the problem is, I have some existing project jars which are included as dependency in this new app. Existing jar also has spring context file with spring 3.X version. My question is, is it possible to have new application as spring boot with dependent jars having context files and those can be imported in spring boot application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to import other Spring XML config files.   You would just replicate the configuration in your current app. If it is really important to use the existing XML config files you can do so with the `@ImportResource` annotation has you would with any Java Config setup.

Or if you are overriding SpringBoot's default and using XML in your new app as well then using the XML import tag option.

```
@ImportResource("classpath:your/package/path/to/existingSppringConfig.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You mentioned, you do not need to import other spring XML files. you would just replicate the configuration in your current app. I really don't get it. I mean if we have spring resources coming from dependent jars, how my new app will understand those beans without having xml file from that jar.

Comment: As I said you would set the configuration of what ever classes and or beans in your actual app.

Comment: I was able to do it successfully as you said using ImportResource.